# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between two display scaling settings

Tags: display, 23.10, scaling

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 and sometimes like to use 100% display scaling and sometimes like to use 125% scaling. I'd like to be able to switch between the two using a keyboard shortcut if possible.

I've tried executing `gsettings list-recursively > before` updating the scaling setting via the Settings menu, then executing `gsettings list-recursively > after` and then doing a diff on the files, and both files seem to be the same. This leads me to think that the scaling setting must be stored/managed elsewhere.

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the scaling setting without going via the settings menu?

Comment: I am doing the same and seeing that `org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` is changing from 1.0 to 1.25.

Comment: Please have a look also at the Gnome extension:  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5111/display-scale-switcher/

Comment: Oh that's quite nice! I've just got my Python script working but may install that too. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Edit**: The following method is for changing text (font) scaling and not screen scaling. But, I keep this answer here, in case it helps somebody else.</sub>

---

Put the following script into a file, say `~/binb/tog_scale.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor)" != "1.0" ]] ; then
  gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
else
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.25
fi
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/binb/tog_scale.sh
```

Then, go to `gnome-control-center` → **Keyboard** → **Keyboard Shortcuts** → (at the bottom of the window) **View and Customize Shortcuts**  → (at the bottom) **Custom Shortcuts** → **+** and enter the following:

**Name:** tog_scale
**Command:** `binb/tog_scale.sh`
**Shortcut:** Any combination you like, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

After that, you can use your keyboard shortcut to toggle between the two scalings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't think that we're talking about the same thing, I'm referring to the scaling in Settings > Screen Display > (enable fractional scaling) > 125%. This scales everything, not just text.

Comment: OK. You are right. I was testing with *font* scaling factor.

Comment: Yeah from what I can see the overall display scaling setting must be stored somewhere else but I'm not sure how to work out where, or if I'll be able to modify it outside of the settings dialog

Comment: The configuration you seek is stored in the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file. Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456788/applying-gnome-wayland-display-settings-monitors-xml-via-automation-command-li

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful, I can indeed see the <scale>1.25</scale> node in the xml file, it will be relatively easy to manipulate that value with a script, I think the hard part will be figuring out how to apply those changes to the current session. The link you've provided suggests using dbus rather than modifying the xml file directly, looks fairly complicated though

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted the script linked by FedKad above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/tutorial.html
# https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/b5f99bd12ebc483e682e39c8126a1b51772bc67d/data/dbus-interfaces/org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.xml
# https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/change-scaling-resolution-of-primary-monitor-from-bash-terminal/19892

import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

display_config_well_known_name = "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig"
display_config_object_path = "/org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig"

display_config_proxy = bus.get_object(display_config_well_known_name, display_config_object_path)
display_config_interface = dbus.Interface(display_config_proxy, dbus_interface=display_config_well_known_name)

serial, physical_monitors, logical_monitors, properties = display_config_interface.GetCurrentState()

updated_logical_monitors=[]
for x, y, scale, transform, primary, linked_monitors_info, props in logical_monitors:
    physical_monitors_config = []
    print(scale)
    new_scale = 1.25 if scale == 1 else 1
    for linked_monitor_connector, linked_monitor_vendor, linked_monitor_product, linked_monitor_serial in linked_monitors_info:
        for monitor_info, monitor_modes, monitor_properties in physical_monitors:
            monitor_connector, monitor_vendor, monitor_product, monitor_serial = monitor_info
            if linked_monitor_connector == monitor_connector:
                for mode_id, mode_width, mode_height, mode_refresh, mode_preferred_scale, mode_supported_scales, mode_properties in monitor_modes:
                    if mode_properties.get("is-current", False): # ( mode_properties provides is-current, is-preferred, is-interlaced, and more)
                        physical_monitors_config.append(dbus.Struct([monitor_connector, mode_id, {}]))
                        # print(linked_monitor_connector)
        # reset x for single monitor
        # if linked_monitor_connector == 'HDMI-2':
        #   x = 0
    updated_logical_monitor_struct = dbus.Struct([dbus.Int32(x), dbus.Int32(y), dbus.Double(new_scale), dbus.UInt32(transform), dbus.Boolean(primary), physical_monitors_config])
    updated_logical_monitors.append(updated_logical_monitor_struct)

properties_to_apply = { "layout_mode": properties.get("layout-mode")}

method = 1 # 2 means show a prompt before applying settings; 1 means instantly apply settings without prompt

display_config_interface.ApplyMonitorsConfig(dbus.UInt32(serial), dbus.UInt32(method), updated_logical_monitors, properties_to_apply)
```

For my use case I used a ternary expression to decide the new scale:

```
 new_scale = 1.25 if scale == 1 else 1
```

This will change the scaling to 1.25 if it is currently 1, if the scale is anything other than 1, it will change it to 1.